# Combine Array Elements in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get an required output from an array.
I am getting data array from a for loop like this:

```
Array
(
[TIMESLOTID] => 27
[DATE] => za 05-04-2014 15:00
[ProductID] => 196
[VariantID] => 1079
)
Array
(
[TIMESLOTID] => 27
[DATE] => za 12-04-2014 15:00
[ProductID] => 196
[VariantID] => 1079
)
Array
(
[TIMESLOTID] => 27
[DATE] => za 29-03-2014 15:00
[ProductID] => 196
[VariantID] => 1079
)
Array
(
[TIMESLOTID] => 23
[DATE] => ma 07-04-2014 10:00
[ProductID] => 196
[VariantID] => 1083
)
```

Now If the values of [TIMESLOTID] , [ProductID] and [VariantID] are matched, they should be merged into one array otherwise in a seperate array. The output will look like:

```
Array
(
[TIMESLOTID] => 27
[DATE] => 
    Array
    (
    [DATE] => za 05-04-2014 15:00,
    [DATE] => za 12-04-2014 15:00,
    [DATE] => za 29-03-2014 15:00
    ),
[ProductID] => 196,
[VariantID] => 1079
),
Array
(
[TIMESLOTID] => 23,
[DATE] => ma 07-04-2014 10:00,
[ProductID] => 196,
[VariantID] => 1083
)
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are expected to show you attempts and tell us where you are stuck exactly.

Comment: @PeeHaa I have managed to track the records from the loop where the values are matched. But I got stuck at combine the date record as given above. I have tries array_merge and array_combine but didn't get the exact format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so, some precisions before any answer.

The array you want to obtain is invalid, for some reasons :

- You can't have multiple keys with the same name.
- For sorting reasons, I'll (imo) use a global array with keys (timeslotID) and values (array with productID, variantID, and dates which is an array with index and values)

So, a valid array would be that :

```
 Array(
     [27] => Array(
               [ProductID] => 196,
               [VariantID] => 1079,
               [Dates] => Array(
                    [0] => 'za 05-04-2014 15:00',
                    [1] => 'za 12-04-2014 15:00'
                    .....
               )
     ),
     [23] => Array(
               [ProductID] => 196,
               [VariantID] => 1083,
               [Dates] => Array(
                    [0] => 'ma 07-04-2014 10:00'
               )
     )
 )
```

If the array is formatted like that, then you'll be able to write a function that converts the input array into an array like that. Hope this helps.

EDIT : now, here's the function responsible of the transformation.
I didn't test it, but it seems algoritmatically good :)

```
function transformArray($inputArray){
    $toReturn = array();

    foreach($inputArray as $product){
        if(in_array($product['TIMESLOTID'],array_keys($toReturn))){
            array_push($toReturn[$product['TIMESLOTID']]['Dates'],$product['DATE']);
        }
        else {
            $toReturn[$product['TIMESLOTID']] = array(
                'ProductID' => $product['ProductID'],
                'VariantID' => $product['VariantID'],
                'Dates' => array(
                    $product['DATE']
                )
            );
        }
     }
     return $toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent. This is exactly what I want. Can you please tell me what I should write inside my for loop to get the above output?

Answer (score -1):

```
$list = array(
        array
        (
        'TIMESLOTID' => 27,
        'DATE' => "05-04-2014 15:00",
        'ProductID' => 196,
        'VariantID' => 1079
        ),

        array
        (
        'TIMESLOTID' => 27,
        'DATE' => "12-05-2014 15:00",
        'ProductID' => 196,
        'VariantID' => 1079
        ),

        array
        (
        'TIMESLOTID' => 27,
        'DATE' => "29-03-2014 15:00",
        'ProductID' => 196,
        'VariantID' => 1079
        ),

        array
        (
        'TIMESLOTID' => 23,
        'DATE' => "07-04-2014 10:00",
        'ProductID' => 196,
        'VariantID' => 1083
        )

    );
    $return = array();

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($list);$i++) {
        if(!array_key_exists($list[$i]['TIMESLOTID'], $return)) {
            $return[$list[$i]['TIMESLOTID']] = $list[$i];
        } else {
            if(sizeof($return[$list[$i]['TIMESLOTID']]['DATE']) == 1) {
                $date = $return[$list[$i]['TIMESLOTID']]['DATE'];
                $return[$list[$i]['TIMESLOTID']]['DATE'] = array($date,$list[$i]['DATE']);
            } else {
                array_push($return[$list[$i]['TIMESLOTID']]['DATE'],$list[$i]['DATE']);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but above is the array which I have and I want to merge the elements as I mentioned below in my question.

Comment: it's merged using the for loop :s , juste test it copy and paste i php file